# Taking the inverse Fourier transform of a function of both frequency and time?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have this function here which is the solution to a PDE. I have never seen a Fourier transform of a function that is both $t$ and $\omega$ dependent. What can I do with this?
$$u(x,t) = \phi(x)*\mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-(9\omega^2+2)t}\Big]\Rightarrow \phi * \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-9\omega^2}e^{-2t}\Big]$$

Here are the steps which lead me to this solution:
$$\textbf{PDE:  } u_t = 9u_{xx} - 2u; \ -\infty<x<\infty$$
$$\textbf{IC:  } u(x,0) = \phi(x)$$
where

$$\phi(x) = 
   \begin{cases}
    1, \ 0\leq x\leq 1\\
    0, \ x \not\in [0,1)
\end{cases} 
$$

Taking the Fourier transform of the PDE and IC:
$$\mathcal{F}[u_t] = 9 \mathcal{F}[u_{xx}] - 2 \mathcal{F}[u]]$$
$$\Rightarrow U_t = -9\omega^2U-2U = -(9\omega^2+2)U$$
and
$$\mathcal{F}[u(x,0)] = \Phi(\omega)$$
Solving the simple ODE:
$$U = \Phi(\omega)e^{-(9\omega^2+2)t}$$
$$u(x,t) = \phi(x)*\mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-(9\omega^2+2)t}\Big]\Rightarrow \phi * \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-9\omega^2}e^{-2t}\Big]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a lot of your confusion is because you use a variable $\omega$ that is quite associated to frequency, i.e. time-dependency, but your Fourier transform is done in the space coordinate.

With respect to this Fourier transform, the time variable $t$ is just a constant. So,
$$
u(x,t) 
= \phi(x)*\mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-(9\omega^2+2)t}\Big]
= \phi * \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-9\omega^2}e^{-2t}\Big]
= \left( \phi * \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[e^{-9\omega^2}\Big]\right) e^{-2t}
.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I should have chose something other than $\omega$.